# Simple Factory Method Pattern Solution for exam

Tags: java, methods, factory, abstract

At the days I have exam on my University. I have simple question about one exercise.

I have to write simple code. I have Abstract class Color with three private int ValueR, ValueG, ValueB. And I have method print().
Okay it's simple.

Now I have to write next class Green which will extend my abstract class. I have to set value of R/G/B to 0/255/0. And use method print() to print "I am a green".

How can I set values without getters and setters? I can't change visibility of Values to public

Any solutions?

Comment: declare a constructor with three arguments in the base class and invoke it from the constructor of the concrete class.

Comment: Where do you want Factory Method pattern in this?

Answer (score 0):

Have I done it right?

```
public abstract class Color{

private int valueR;
private int valueG;
private int valueB;

public Color (int valueR, int valueG, int valueB){
    this.valueR = valueR;
    this.valueG = valueG;
    this.valueB = valueB;
}   

void print(){
}
}


class Green extends Color{

public Green(){
    super(0, 255, 0);
}

void print(){
    System.out.println("I am a green!");
}}
```